# HoloLens 2 Research Mode with Unreal - How?

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, unreal-engine4, hololens

I'm new here, so feel free to give tips where needed. I am running into trouble using the Unreal engine combined with the HoloLens 2.

**I would like** to access the special black/white cameras of the HoloLens, for tracking purposes. These are normally not accessible. However, they can be activated by using the “perceptionSensorsExperimental” capability. This should be possible, since it also works with Unity: https://github.com/doughtmw/HoloLensForCV-Unity

**I have tried** to add the capability in the Unreal Project Settings: Config\HoloLens\HoloLensEngine.ini” -> “+RescapCapabilityList=perceptionSensorsExperimental”. The project still builds as expected, but I noticed that it doesn’t matter what I add here. Even something random like “+abcd=efgh” doesn’t break the build.
However, if I add “+CapabilityList=perceptionSensorsExperimental”, I get “Packaging (HoloLens):   ERROR: The 'Name' attribute is invalid - The value 'perceptionSensorsExperimental' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/types:ST_Capability_Foundation' - The Enumeration constraint failed.”. I conclude: 1.) I’m making the changes in the right file. 2.) The right scheme needs to be configured in order for “+RescapCapabilityList=perceptionSensorsExperimental” to work as expected.

**My question** is how do I add the right schema to my Unreal project? (like in the Unity example referenced above, which uses “http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities”), I cannot find any example and I cannot find any proper place to put it. Not in the settings, not in the xml/ini files. Clearly, I am missing something.

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Updated. We released [HoloLens-ResearchMode-Unreal plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/HoloLens-ResearchMode-Unreal)

Comment: Thank you for your response Andrey! I also need to report on the technical difficulties. Do happen to have any sources that confirm this, or perhaps other means that indicate this?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't completely understand what you wrote. Which difficulties? What sources, UE4?

Comment: The technical difficulty: 
Not being able to use HoloLens Research Mode with Unreal. 

Do you have any links to resources that further elaborate on why it is impossible to enable the perceptionSensorsExperimental capability?

Comment: The Unreal development docs are here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unreal/unreal-development-overview?tabs=ue426%2Cmrtk%2Casa

No specific docs for HoloLens Research Mode with Unreal because it's not implemented. You can write me andrey.chistyakov@microsoft.com and we can discuss what I can help you.